# How can I debug gradle plugin

Tags: debugging, android-studio, intellij-idea, gradle

I have written an andrioid gradle plugin with IntelliJ.And I used it in an Android application.I would like to debug the plugin.So I tried to  create a remote debug in IntelliJ
[image]

Then do something in Android Studio.
Excute
`export GRADLE_OPTS="-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=5005"` 
and
 `./gradlew showTips --no-daemon`
.The result is the IJ debugger can connect to VM,but did not STOP at the breakpoint.
My plugin code is this
[image]

The resule in IJ is this ,and never stop at the breakpoint

```
Connected to the target VM, address: 'localhost:5005', transport: 'socket'
Disconnected from the target VM, address: 'localhost:5005', transport: 'socket'
```

What can I do to make the breakpoint to be useful

Comment: I'm guessing the gradle daemon is complicating things with multiple JVM's. You could [disable the daemon](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/gradle_daemon.html#sec:disabling_the_daemon) by adding `org.gradle.daemon=false` to `gradle.properties`

Comment: @LanceJava Thanks, I tried it，but it didnot take effect

Answer (score 0):

I think you also need to set a debug property for gradle. `-Dorg.gradle.debug=true`

```
org.gradle.debug
    When set to true, Gradle will run the build with remote debugging enabled,
    listening on port 5005. Note that this is the equivalent of adding
    -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=5005
    to the JVM command line and will suspend the virtual machine until a
    debugger is attached.
```

https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html#sec:gradle_configuration_properties

Comment: I tried to add `-Dorg.gradle.debug=true` in the gradle.properties,but it didnot take effect. Can groovy code be debugged?

Comment: Can this groovy file remote debug?

Comment: Groovy code can be debugged but that was from this thread about debugging... https://discuss.gradle.org/t/how-do-you-attach-a-debugger-to-gradle-so-that-i-can-debug-it-running-a-task/7526/5

Comment: Also you might want to source this question/answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/11129708/873237

Comment: thanks，but it is a bit different.My problem is the debugger can connected but not stop at breakpoint.